# Why is tqdm printing to a newline instead of updating the same line?

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I'm working on a small command-line game in python where I am showing a progress bar using the tqdm module. I listen for user input using the msvcrt module to interrupt the progress. Once interrupted, the user can restart by entering 'restart' into the command line prompt. The second time the progress bar is shown, instead of updating the same line with the progress, it creates a new line each time.

How would I get it to show the progress on the same line?

[image: Progress bar issue]

This code snippet illustrates my use of the progress bar.

```
def transfer():
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(1000), desc="Transfer progress", ncols=100, bar_format='{l_bar}{bar}|'):
        sleep(.1)
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            if msvcrt.getwche() == ' ':
                interrupt()
                break

def interrupt():
    type("File transfer interrupted, to restart the transfer, type 'restart'")
```

Comment: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/375

Comment: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/313

Comment: Is there a place that explains WHY this happens?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Try with `position=0` and `leave=True`

(Solution working in **Google Colab** to avoid printing to a newline)

```
from tqdm import tqdm 
import time

def foo_():
    time.sleep(0.3)
range_ = range(0, 10)
total = len(range_)

with tqdm(total=total, position=0, leave=True) as pbar:
   for i in tqdm((foo_, range_ ), position=0, leave=True):
    pbar.update()
```

Comment: If you make a colab cell with `from functools import partial`, `from tqdm import tqdm`, `tqdm = partial(tqdm, position=0, leave=True)` at the top of your notebook, this will set it up so you can just call `tqdm(iterable)` and it will work nicely in colab.

Comment: `for i in tqdm(range(n), position=0, leave=True)` also works for me in PyCharm

Comment: This also works in both jupyterlab and terminal.

Comment: instead of tqdm.tqdm. Use tqdm.auto.tqdm

Comment: Will this work if tqdm is used internally by a package? I'd guess no since the package would have it's own `from tqdm import tqdm` statement or similar.

Comment: I didn't need to set `leave=True`. This seems to be the default.

Answer (score 44):

I faced this problem a lot and sometimes `position = 0` & `leave = True` does not works. So, I found one alternate way.
Instead of **tqdm.tqdm** you can use **tqdm.auto.tqdm**
or 
instead of

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

try using

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
```

Comment: This formats nicely in Jupyter Notebooks/Jupyter Lab as well

Comment: This works in VS Code Notebooks too.

Comment: Confirm it works in Google Colab.

Comment: This works nicely in jupyter notebooks!

Answer (score 37):

I have realized that closing tqdm instances before using tqdm again fixes the problem of printing status bar in a new line on Jupyter Lab:

```
while len(tqdm._instances) > 0:
    tqdm._instances.pop().close()
```

Or even better, thanks to Nirmal for the suggestion:

```
tqdm._instances.clear()
```

Comment: Damn, this whole time I've been restarting Jupyter notebooks to fix the multiline stuff. This is really helpful, thanks!

Comment: this solved it!

Answer (score 35):

**tqdm_notebook** is deprecated. You must use **tq.notebook.tqdm** instead.

```
import tqdm.notebook as tq
for i in tq.tqdm(...):
```

Furthermore, tqdm_notebook was really miserable in terms of performances. That's fully corrected with the new library.

Comment: This displays no progress bar in a jupyter Lab session

Comment: How did you works with `asyncio` without `tqdm.asyncio`?

Comment: @00__00__00 you´d need to install / update ipywidgeds and activate it [Widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html)

```bash
pip install ipywidgets


jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```s

Answer (score 19):

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
```

this command works in google colab.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `tqdm.tqdm.write` in place of the standard `print()`

This will print above the progress bar and move the progress bar one row below.

I tested this using below code, pressing `space` will print into stdout but not break the loop.
It was not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve, since the `interrupt()` function of yours only checks the type of the provided string. [type() built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

```
import tqdm
import msvcrt
from time import sleep

def transfer():
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(1000), desc="Transfer progress", ncols=100, bar_format='{l_bar}{bar}|'):
        sleep(.1)
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            if msvcrt.getwche() == ' ':
                interrupt()
                # break

def interrupt():
    tqdm.tqdm.write("File transfer interrupted, to restart the transfer, type 'restart'", end="")

transfer()
```

EDIT: to include `end` parameter of `tqdm.write()` as noted by Paul Netherwood
[tqdm.tqdm.write()](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#write)

Comment: Note that tqdm.write() has an optional parameter 'end' which defaults to '\n' which will cause a line wrap. Set end=''

Answer (score 7):

`from tqdm import notebook`

Instead of `tqdm(looping)` 
Use `notebook.tqdm(looping)`

Answer (score 7):

If you encounter this problem while using `tqdm` on colab or jupyter notebook, then ...

Use notebook/colab version of `tqdm`

```
>>> from tqdm.notebook import trange, tqdm
>>> for i in trange(1000):
...     ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides the aforementioned `position=0, leave=True` parameters, in my case the `tqdm`'s default `ascii=False` parameter was also printing on new lines after a few iterations. You easily identify if this is the case by looking at the progress bar: if there are any weirdly formatted symbols (e.g. question marks) in your progress bar, you should try using `ascii=True`.

So this worked for me:

```py
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
...

with tqdm(data, position=0, leave=True, ascii=True) as iterator:
   for x in iterator:
      # do stuff
      ...

      iterator.set_postfix_str(msg)
```

Answer (score 4):

You might have imported tqdm twice. Restart the whole notebook kernel and run again. It will solve the issue. It might also be showing because of any print statements inside the tqdm

Answer (score 3):

The following is hacky, but seems to work reasonably well to reset tqdm:

```
from tqdm import tqdm as tqdm_base
def tqdm(*args, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(tqdm_base, '_instances'):
        for instance in list(tqdm_base._instances):
            tqdm_base._decr_instances(instance)
    return tqdm_base(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sometimes previous output is printed at the start (which I am not sure how to remove), but I find it much less annoying than newlines (especially in long loops).

Comment: This works very well, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Import `tqdm`.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

First start the code, where you use `tqdm`, stop it because of multiple lines output.

Then do:

```
list(getattr(tqdm, '_instances'))

for instance in list(tqdm._instances):
    tqdm._decr_instances(instance)
```

If you get an error:

> AttributeError: type object 'tqdm' has no attribute '_instances'

You need **first to start your code, where you use `tqdm` and only after that start code which mention.**

And after all this manipulations your `tqdm` will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The issue I'm having might not be common, but in case it's useful to anyone, I was printing another variable to the console. Disabling that print fixes the issue.

Comment: THIS IS KEY! If you have any print statement, it will mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

`leave=False` for the inner loop worked in my case.

```
for j in tqdm(outer_list):
    for i in tqdm(inner_list, leave=False):
```

Evnironment with `tqdm==4.38.0` and `Python 3.6.7`

Comment: Works also for multiple loops in the terminal, not in notebook (they all stay in place)

Answer (score 1):

Although the original question looks to be for a Linux shell. From the **Windows command line**, the following worked.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for x in tqdm([1,2,3,4], leave=True, ncols=80, position=0):
    pass
    for y in tqdm([1,2,3,4], leave=False, ncols=80, position=1):
        pass
```

I feel that if i'd read the documentation, rather than blindly trying all the suggested fixes, i'd have sorted this much quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tqdm.tnrange()`

`for i in tqdm.tnrange(len(df)):`

[image: Ongoing image]
[image: finished image]

Comment: Please include code as codeblocks instead of images so as to make it easier to copy/paste (and also reduce Stack Overflow's hosting cost)

Comment: Ah sorry, but the code  just `for i in tqdm.tnrange(len(df)):` rest is for jupyter as printing in newline also happens inside notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried tqdm solution but as I'm using Spyder (Anaconda) it doesn't work in my case as supposed due to mentioned in other answers conflict between write and print commands. I came up with simple and working although not fanciest solution.

```
def ybar(progr, total, step=50):
    #starts with 1
    l2=(progr/total)//(1/step)
    if progr==1: print(f'[{total}]: '+'|'*int(l2), end = '') 
    else:
        l1=((progr-1)/total)//(1/step) 

        ll=int(l2-l1)
        if l1 < l2: 

            for j in range(1,ll+1):
                if (int(l1)+j)%5==0:
                    print('*', end = '')
                else:
                    print('|', end = '')
        if progr==total: print("  DONE")
```

And as result you'll get simple: [100]: *||||*||

```
for i in range(1,101):
    ybar(i,len(range(1,101)),50)
    #something
```

There are plenty of solutions here: [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#parameters
I think sometimes tqdm cannot catch the screen width
use ncols=xx to restrict line width
ex:
tqdm(iter,ncols=80):   # restrict line width=80

Answer (score 0):

Try with `leave=True` and `position=1`.

Worked for me in kaggle.

Answer (score -8):

Try `from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm` instead of `from tqdm import tqdm`.

Comment: really? That's for jupyter/ipython notebooks and really doesn't seem applicable here.