# TQDM surges while using sub-class models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tqdm

Good Morning,Afternoon,and Evening.
I'm new to TF and ML right now, learning things from beautiful book Handsonml2.

I'm at the sub-class model page right now, but something awkward happened.

Usually, when we are training our model, we see this.
[normally-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kIdF.png)

tqdm prints every epochs, showing progress greatly.

however, when I use sub-class model, then things go like this.
[TQDM surges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2HrD.png)

It seems like something in the class is interrupting the tqdm, making it prints as much as it can.
these are my codes for the model class.

```
class WideAndDeepModel(keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, units=30, activation="relu", **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
      self.hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
      self.main_output = keras.layers.Dense(1)
      self.aux_output = keras.layers.Dense(1)
    
    def call(self, inputs):
      input_A, input_B = inputs
      hidden1 = self.hidden1(input_B)
      hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
      concat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A, hidden2])
      main_output = self.main_output(concat)
      aux_output = self.aux_output(hidden2)
      return main_output, aux_output

model = WideAndDeepModel(30, activation="relu")
```

it makes odd response like pic #2,
while it does not make any problem if I use almost same APIs
but do it in functions.

It's like

```
input_A = keras.layers.Input(shape=[5], name="wide_input")
input_B = keras.layers.Input(shape=[6], name="deep_input")
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(input_B)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(hidden1)
concat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A, hidden2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="output")(concat)
aux_output = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="aux_output")(hidden2)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_A, input_B], outputs=[output])
```

Does anybody knows why? Is it possible to prevent?
I'll wait for the answer.

*It does not make that results if I erase the Aux output parts.
Yet, I want to know why it is happening...

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code as currently the indentation of the functions of your class `WideAndDeepModel` is not valid. Further, please try to [minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your example.

Comment: @flyingdutchman sry for crude works, I'll edit as much as I can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707229/tqdm-printing-to-newline

Comment: @ML_Engine Mine was simpler than those people... I just made my IDE terminal wider...

Answer (score 0):

Answer was Surprisingly Simple.
Tqdm prints on new line if the line is too long to present in one line,
therefore making the terminal wider simply corrected the problem.

-Problem Solved-