# Finding the missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset of students, each student has its own csv file,
Dataset B has 297,444 csv files, I want to know which student csv file is missing in that dataset.

Like you see in this picture, there's no u2.csv file present in that dataset so how can I check which all of the csv files that are missing using pandas?

Here's the code I tried so far

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

path = r'C:/Users/user1/Desktop/EDNET DATA/EdNet-KT4/KT4' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for i,filename in enumerate (all_files):
    
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, ',' ,index_col=None, header=0).assign(user_iD=filename.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0])
    
    li.append(df)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df = data.copy()

df.isnull().sum()

df.to_feather('KT4.ftr')
data1= pd.read_feather('KT4.ftr')
data1.head()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Add the existing code, how are you accessing the files.

Comment: I have just concatinated all those csv files into a single feather file, and as of yet I just checked what are the missing values (Nan Values) present inside the dataset, 

I'm not sure how to check which of the csv files are missing?

Comment: Try some easier thing first: Get a list of all student names, then a list of all file names. Then loop through all student names and for each check if it is in the other list. no need to read the files

Comment: Cannot get a list of all student names, This is a public dataset available on Github, It's not my personal dataset

Comment: In the loop where you are enumerating on the file names,  why don't you get the number value using `filename[1:]` and compare it with another variable say `num` and while they are not equal increment `num` untill they are equal and store the missing file in a list or so.
Of course you have to sort the list of file names first before entering the loop.

Comment: I don't think you should use pandas for that. Just create a list of all the files in the directory, remove the 'u' prefix, and then find the missing numbers (you can create a new list of all the numbers from 1 to the max number in your original list), and then remove from the new list the numbers from the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

> **Note**: You only need the list of files names. But what you are doing in the code you posted, is reading the contents of the files (*which is not what you want*)!

You could choose to use any of the following two methods. For the sake of reproducibility, I have created some dummy data and I tested the solution on Google Colab. I found that using pandas (**Method-2**) was somehow faster.

[image: Open In Colab]

### Common Code

```py
import glob
# import pandas as pd

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# I am deliberately using this for 
#   a small number of students to 
#   test the code.
num_students = 20 # 297444
```

### Method-1: Simple Python Loop

- For `100,000` files, it took around **1min 29s** on Google Colab.
- Run the following in a jupyter-notebook cell.

```py
%%time
missing_files = []

for i in range(15):
    student_file = f'u{i}.csv'
    if f'{path}/{student_file}' not in all_files:
        missing_files.append(student_file)

#print(f"Total missing: {len(missing_files)}")
#print(missing_files)

## Runtime
# CPU times: user 1min 29s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1min 29s
# Wall time: 1min 29s
```

### Method-2: Process using Pandas library (*faster*)

- For `100,000` files, it took around **358 ms** on Google Colab.
- Almost **`250 times` FASTER** than method-1.
- Run the following in a jupyter-notebook cell.

```py
%%time
# import pandas as pd

existing_student_ids = (
    pd.DataFrame({'Filename': all_files})
      .Filename.str.extract(f'{path}/u(?P<StudentID>\d+)\.csv')
      .astype(int)
      .sort_values('StudentID')
      .StudentID.to_list()
)

missing_student_ids = list(set(range(num_students)) - set(existing_student_ids))

# print(f"Total missing students: {len(missing_student_ids)}")
# print(f'missing_student_ids: {missing_student_ids}')

## Runtime
# CPU times: user 323 ms, sys: 31.1 ms, total: 354 ms
# Wall time: 358 ms
```

### Dummy Data

Here I will define some dummy data for the purpose of making
the solution reproducible and easily testable.

I will skip the following student-ids (`skip_student_ids`) and NOT create any `.csv` file for them.

```py
import os

NUM_STUDENTS = 20

## CREATE FILE NAMES
num_students = NUM_STUDENTS
skip_student_ids = [3, 8, 10, 13] ## --> we will skip these student-ids
skip_files = [f'u{i}.csv' for i in skip_student_ids]
all_files = [f'u{i}.csv' for i in range(num_students) if i not in skip_student_ids]

if num_students <= 20:
    print(f'skip_files: {skip_files}')
    print(f'all_files: {all_files}')

## CREATE FILES
path = 'test'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
for filename in all_files:
    with open(path + '/' + filename, 'w') as f:
        student_id = str(filename).split(".")[0].replace('u', '')
        content = f"""
        Filename,StudentID
        {filename},{student_id}
        """
        f.write(content)
```

### References

1. [`pandas.Series.str.extract` - Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)
2. [Can I add message to the tqdm progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506645/can-i-add-message-to-the-tqdm-progressbar)

Comment: @haseeb-sultan Please take a look at this. I hope this is what you are looking for.